# AUTOCAD INTERNAL ERROR

Tags: autocad

AUTOCAD  2016 no add-ons.
Yesterday, saved the file and went out, now it does not open. Writes this:
INTERNAL ERROR: !saveres.cpp@440:eGeneralMoldingFailure. 
What to do now? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, you must try to recover the file using the standard tools of autocad:
**File -> Utilities -> Recover**
 either by typing at the command prompt
**_.RECOVER**
If you still will give this error, then you can try some online service https://onlinefile.repair/en/autocad.html

Comment: I tried to do as was stated in the instructions but I keep getting the same error. so I decided to try the online service. almost 90% managed to save. I think for me it is very  not bad. thank you)